# My div element takes more space than required. How can I get rid of that space?

Tags: html, css, image, bootstrap-4

I am trying to center pictures and align text to its left edge.

I was thinking the best thing is to have a div with `width: fit-content`.
However here is something interesting I get and cannot solve.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Here is my code:

HTML code:

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="column">
                    <div id="imageContainer">
                        <img id="imgWidth" src="{%  static 'kuzaneli/img/New folder/12.png' %}" alt="..."/>
                        <div id="imageText"><div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="column">
                    <div id="imageContainer">
                        <img id="imgWidth" src="{%  static 'kuzaneli/img/New folder/li.png' %}" alt="..."/>
                        <div id="imageText"><div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</div>
```

CSS code:

```
.row{
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: fit-content;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.column{
    flex: 50%;

}

#imageContainer{

}


#imageContainer{
    width: fit-content !important;
}

#imgWidth{
    width: 70%;
    height: auto;
}

#imageText{
    width: fit-content;
}
```

I want to get rid of the extra space I am having in the div, where I have image and text. How can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> when you are using bootstrap, it is better to use its classes for layout your document. In the code below I posted the html and css that I was used. In the html tags I used bootstrap classes for making img tag "responsive" and aligning texts and images. the link below from bootstrap documentation could be helpful:
> https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/images/

> I think it is necessary to mention that if you are using lots of images in your code, it is better to make the size of them similar. for example all of them have 168px width and 300px height. because if they have different sizes you probably have some problems in your layout.

> in the css code I added a "max-width=168px" according to my image size, you can change it to whatever your image width is.

```css
.imageContainer {
  border: 2px solid #258221;
  max-width : 168px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>center-img</title>

  <!-- links -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
               <div class="col-sm text-center">
                    <div class="imageContainer" class="text-left">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/birds.jpg"/>
                        <div class="text-left">
                          <div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="col-sm text-center">
                    <div class="imageContainer" class="text-left">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/view.jpg"/>
                        <div class="text-left" id="imageText"><div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
</div>

  <script src="js-files/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

> you need to add your image sources and bootstrap to make it functional.enter image description here

[image: one-column image]

Comment: How can I make the column smaller? All my pictures have fixed size, therefore I have no problem with that. I just need them to not look large, is there possibility of making a smaller column than picture and fill it with image

Comment: I added the "col-sm" class for better showing. if you do not need you only could delete them and only use ".imageContainer" div in your layout.

Comment: This answer didn't exactly solved my problem however it gave me enough information to have fixed it. I changed to your code and added some paddings which eventually reduced sizes.

Answer (score 1):

instead you can make the contents to fill the available space.
in this case let the image to fill all the space available.

```
#imgWidth{
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: Yes however I want then to be small. In that case is there a way to reduce their size from outer elements?

Answer (score 0):

> this is the code

```html
<div class="container">
            <div class="row">
              <!--  <div class="col-sm text-center"> -->
                    <div class="imageContainer" class="text-left">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/birds.jpg"/>
                        <div class="text-left">
                          <div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
             <!--    </div> -->

               <!--  <div class="col-sm text-center"> -->
                    <div class="imageContainer" class="text-left">
                        <img class="img-fluid" src="img/view.jpg"/>
                        <div class="text-left" id="imageText"><div> Jacqueline Mon Amour </div><div> 25.00 Eur </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
              <!--   </div> -->

            </div>
</div>
```